# Normal covering of the wedge of two circles

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I am confused about the following covering space of the wedge of two circles is not a normal covering, which is at p.58 in Hatcher's book.

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: There is no automorphism of the graph that takes the indicated basepoint to the vertex just above it.

Comment: Yes, I see.  Does the Deck group of this covering space just equal to $Z_2?$

Comment: Looks that way to me!